# How to create a diff column in groups mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table from the following struct:

```
   Id_no | year |
   --------------
   22222 | 1999 |
   22255 | 2000 |
   .....
```

I'm trying to create a diff column for a table with the following structure, so that it will be done individually to each id:

```
   Id_no | year | diff
   --------------------
   22222 | 1999 | 0
   22222 | 2000 | 1
   22222 | 2005 | 5
   55555 | 2000 | 0
   55555 | 2014 | 14
```

I have tried to do the following:

```
  select x.Id_no,
        x.year,
        IFNULL(x.year - max(y.year), 0) AS diff
  from my_table x
  left 
  join my_table y
  on y.year < x.year
  group by  
     x.Id_no, 
     x.year
  order by x.Id_no
```

the results are not as expected I suspect that the calculation of the diff is not working as i expected for example:

```
     Id_no | year | diff
     ----------------------
     2898  | 1997 |  1   
     2898  | 1989 |  2
```

the diff between 1997 and 1989 is not 2

Comment: You example data has two different `id_no`s.  I'm not sure what the expected results are supposed to mean.

Comment: You are correct, i have fixed my example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, coalesce(year - prev_year, 0) as diff
from (select t.*,
             (select max(t2.year)
              from my_table t2
              where t2.id_no = t.id_no and
                    t2.year < t.year
             ) prev_year
      from my_table t
     ) t;
```

This avoids the `group by` on all the data and can make use of an index on `my_table(id_no, year)`.

Also, the middle subquery is not necessary.  I just included it so you could see both the previous year and the difference.